# Searching of strings in a single string in python

Tags: python

In this code, how can I check multiple strings in a single string in single statement?

```
line = '{        AutoLogin = 0;        Captive = 0;        Closed = 0;        Disabled = 0;        LastConnected = "2013-11-27 08:38:10 +0000";        Passpoint = 0;        PossiblyHiddenNetwork = 0;        SPRoaming = 0;        SSID = <534253>;        SSIDString = SBS;        SecurityType = "WPA/WPA2 Personal";        SystemMode = 1;        TemporarilyDisabled = 0;    })'

for token in line.split( ';' ):
    if 'RecentNetworks' in token:
        start = True
    if 'LastConnected' in token:
        start = True
```

Comment: Will be "line" a JSON, in this case maybe is easier parse the string as a json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for token in line.split(';'):
    start = any(s in token for s in ["RecentNetworks", "LastConnected"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
if re.search(r'RecentNetworks|LastConnected', token):
    start = True
```

I'm not sure if this is faster than the `any` solution, but I assume it.